How does time dilation affect the synchronization of clocks in different gravitational potentials?
How does time dilation affect the synchronization of clocks in different gravitational potentials, as described by the general theory of relativity?
For example if we consider two clocks, one located at sea level and another at a high altitude (e.g., on a mountain), how would the difference in gravitational potential between the two locations influence the rate at which each clock ticks, and what implications does this have for the Global Positioning System (GPS) satellites, which operate at a higher altitude and experience both gravitational time dilation and special relativistic effects due to their velocities?
Ive always been fascinated by this, but ive never had the chance to ask the question.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/why-does-gps-depend-on-relativity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

This might help - Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?

Related: in 2005 or so, Tom Van Baak took a few atomic clocks in a van w/ his kids on a road trip up Mt Ranier, to experimentally show the effect. Physics Today article - there’s more info on his website but it’s not https

This is one rare case where relativity works exactly the way it would seem to. High-altitude clocks appear, from the ground, to tick faster, while low-altitude clocks appear, from the sky, to tick slower. This is actually one of the most obvious confirmations of general relativity: we can measure this effect very precisely using atomic clocks, and a simple experiment you can do is bringing an atomic clock up on top of a mountain for a few days and then comparing it with one that was left on the ground.
This is also apparent on jet aircraft and spacecraft; atomic clocks up there/moving fast show that there is time dilation when you're moving quickly that pretty much matches what we'd predict with special/general relativity. It only adds up to a few milliseconds every few months, but it's measurable, and atomic clocks are sufficiently precise to measure it.

what implications does this have for the Global Positioning System (GPS) satellites, which operate at a higher altitude and experience both gravitational time dilation and special relativistic effects due to their velocities?

When people say that relativity can't be real because [insert half-misunderstood thought experiment here], one of the most common answers they get is "your GPS wouldn't work if relativity weren't real." Why? Because GPS satellites in fact do have to account for relativity.
The way they work involves having multiple different satellites identifying their precise distance to you using light signal timing. The satellites, all communicating with each other, can then triangulate your position and send that position information down to you on Earth. If relativity weren't accounted for (both in the finite speed of light as well as relativity of simultaneity/time dilation/other effects), your GPS would not be able to get as good a read on your position as it can because when you're trying to pinpoint the origin of a signal down to a few feet from hundreds of miles away while you're moving at high speed relativistic effects do matter and they need to be accounted for.
See the first answer to the related question: GPS satellites, in order to do this triangulation, need to keep time down to a precision of 50 nanoseconds. Given that time dilation causes timekeeping errors of up to 38 microseconds per day, or 4.4 nanoseconds per second (the units get a little weird), it's clear that not dealing with that time dilation isn't going to cut it (to be clear: 50 nanosecond-precision gets too noisy to have much certainty anymore after around 10-15 seconds, at that rate).

Last I checked the GPS satellites do not compute your position.  They just broadcast their location and time.  Your receiver is responsible for calculating your position based on the data it receives.

In your second sentence you use the word 'appear'; "High-altitude clocks appear, from the ground, to tick faster [...]" I take it the meaning you intend is that you could also have written: "High-altitude clocks are observed to tick faster compared to lower altitude [...]" I think the word 'appear' is ambiguous here, because it could also be interpreted in the sense of 'apparent difference', as opposed to 'real difference'. In order to not have that ambiguity I prefer the phrasing: 'for clocks located at high altitude a larger amount of proper time elapses than for clocks at lower altitude.

38 μs per day is $0.44\ \mathrm{ns}/\mathrm{s} = 4.4 \cdot 10^{-10}$.

@RossMillikan This answer in some parts uses the word "GPS" in its colloquial usage of "GPS receiver" or device, instead of the pure "Global Positioning System".

Sorry to get back to this late - yes, Pablo, I was being imprecise. (The net effect is still the same - correcting for relativity is still a thing the satellites have to do to get accurate data to the receiver on the ground whence the position is computed.)

When at rest in a quasistatic gravitational field, a clock at a location whose gravitational potential is higher by $\Delta\Phi$ ticks faster by a factor $1 + c^{-2}\Delta\Phi$ to lowest order. For small differences in position, this becomes $1 - c^{-2}\mathbf{g} \cdot \Delta\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{g}$ is the local gravitational field ($\mathbf{g} = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}\Phi$).
Note that for the rotating Earth, it is the apparent gravitational field (including the centrifugal effect) that enters here.
Namely, the Earth's rotation at angular speed $\omega$ means that a clock at rest relative to the Earth (not in orbit unless geostationary) moves at speed $v = \omega r_\perp$, where $r_\perp$ is the distance from the Earth's axis. Motional time dilation slows down the clock by a factor $1 - \frac{1}{2}c^{-2}v^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}c^{-2}\omega^2 r_\perp^2$ to lowest order. For a small difference in position, the combined gravitational and motional effect is then a factor
$$1 - c^{-2}\mathbf{g} \cdot \Delta\mathbf{r} - c^{-2}\omega^2 r_\perp\Delta r_\perp = 1 - c^{-2}(\mathbf{g} + \omega^2\mathbf{r}_\perp) \cdot \Delta\mathbf{r}.$$
In other words, the result is as if we used the apparent potential $\Phi - \frac{1}{2}\omega^2 r_\perp^2$ or apparent field $\mathbf{g} + \omega^2\mathbf{r}_\perp$, where gravity is supplemented with a centrifugal acceleration directed away from the Earth's axis. This apparent field is the one observed on the Earth with levels and plumb bobs.


How does time dilation affect the synchronization of clocks in
different gravitational potentials, as described by the general theory
of relativity?

Clocks at different gravitational potentials cannot be synchronised in the conventional sense used in SR using Einstein clock synchronisation convention. The clocks run at different rates, so in order to synchronise the clocks, one of the clocks has to have its output multiplied by a factor, so that it runs at the same rate as the other clock.

For example if we consider two clocks, one located at sea level and
another at a high altitude (e.g., on a mountain), how would the
difference in gravitational potential between the two locations
influence the rate at which each clock ticks

As you go up a mountain there are two opposing effects. Gravitational time dilation speeds up clocks due to being further away from the centre of the Earth. Velocity related time dilation slows down clocks due the higher tangential velocity that results from being at a greater radius from the centre of rotation of a rotating body. In broad terms, the gravitational effect dominates and clocks speed up as you go up a mountain.
The best way to calculate the exact result for time dilation in the gravitational field of a non-rotating spherically symmetric body, is to use the Schwarzschild metric:
$$\begin{equation}
 \mathrm d\tau^2 = \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right) \mathrm dt^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)^{-1} \frac{dr^2}{c^2} - \frac{r^2}{c^2} \left(\mathrm d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \, \mathrm d\phi^2\right)\end{equation},$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time of a particle moving in the gravitational field and all other quantities are as measured by a reference observer at infinity. For constant radius $(r)$, $\mathrm dr=0$ and for circular motion in the equatorial plane, ($\theta = \pi/2$) and $(\mathrm d\phi = 0)$, the above equation simplifies to:
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d\tau^2}{\mathrm dt^2} = \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)  - \frac{r^2}{c^2} \left(\frac{\mathrm d\theta^2}{\mathrm dt^2} \right)\end{equation}.$$
Since $\mathrm d\theta/\mathrm dt$ is equal to the angular velocity $\omega$, we can replace that expression with $\frac{\mathrm d\theta }{\mathrm dt} = \omega_{\infty} = \frac{v_{\infty}}{r}$ where $\omega_{\infty}$ and $v_{\infty}$ are the angular velocity and the horizontal tangential velocity respectively, both according to the Schwarzschild observer at $r = \infty$. We can now conveniently rewrite the metric as:
$$\rightarrow \mathrm d\tau= \mathrm dt \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}  -  \frac{v_{\infty}^2}{c^2} }.\tag{1}$$
We now have a nice expression of time dilation as a function of gravitational potential and velocity. Since the coordinate velocity $(v_{\infty})$ measured at infinity is slower than the local velocity $(v)$ measured by a local observer at $r$ that is stationary relative to the gravitational field, by a factor of $\sqrt{1-2GM/(rc^2)}$, the metric can be written in terms of local velocity as:
$$\rightarrow \mathrm d\tau= \mathrm dt \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}  -  \frac{v^2}{c^2}\left(1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)}. \tag{2}$$
When the local velocity of a particle is measured to be $c$, the above equation collapses to $\tau = 0$, which is the expected result for a photon, indicating we are on the right path.
The above equation can be factored to:
$$\rightarrow \mathrm d\tau= \mathrm dt\ \sqrt{\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)}\ \sqrt{\left( 1 -  \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)}. \tag{3}$$
And now, it can be seen that the total time dilation is simply the product of the gravitational time dilation factor and the velocity time dilation of special relativity, when we use local velocity.
For an inertial particle following a circular orbit, we can use the well-known equation
$$v_{\infty}=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}\tag{4}.$$
Substituting this expression into equation $(1)$ gives us the fairly well-known equation:
$$\mathrm d\tau = \mathrm dt \sqrt{ 1- \frac{3GM}{rc^2}},\tag{5}$$
I have digressed a bit from the main question, but I wanted to show that the relatively little-known equation $(3)$ is exact and consistent with known results of the Schwarzschild metric.
So far, we have only considered horizontal tangential velocity.
Vertical velocity is subject to both gravitational length contraction and gravitational time dilation, so the coordinate vertical velocity $v_{\parallel \infty}$ in terms of local velocity is subject to the inverse gravitational gamma factor squared. When we express the vertical coordinate velocity ($dr/dt$) in terms of local velocity, we end up with equation (2) again, confirming that equation (3) is universal and independent of the direction of the velocity as long as we use local velocity.
So far, we have only compared the proper time of an arbitrary clock moving in a gravitational field to a static clock at infinity. To compare the proper time of a clock at radius $r_1$ with local velocity $v_1$ with another clock at radius $r_2$ with local velocity $v_2$, we use:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\tau_1}{\mathrm d\tau_2} = \frac{\sqrt{\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r_1c^2}\right) \left( 1 -  \frac{v_1^2}{c^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r_2c^2}\right) \left( 1 -  \frac{v_2^2}{c^2}\right)}}\tag{6}$$
It is easy enough to plug in values for a GPS satellite and a clock on the surface of the Earth into the above equation to find the required time dilation adjustment factor for the GPS satellite so that it synchronises with the ground clock.
It can also be seen that if $r_1=r_2$, then the gravitational time dilation factors cancel out, and locally, the equations of special relativity apply even in a gravitational field.
All the above assumes the Earth is not rotating. If we want to be really fussy, we should probably use the Kerr metric for a rotating gravitational body, and, using the same procedures as used for the Schwarzschild metric, we end up with:
$$\mathrm d\tau= \mathrm dt \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}  -  \frac{v_{\infty}^2}{c^2} +\frac{4GJ_{\infty}}{rc^3} - \frac{J_{\infty}v_{\infty}}{M^2 r^2 c^4}      }$$
which is basically the same as equation $(1)$ obtained from the Schwarzschild metric with a couple of extra terms to account for the rotation of the gravitational body. As far as I know, the Kerr metric is not used to calibrate the GPS satellite clocks. It may be that the additional terms are insignificant for the Earth, and some people would dispute whether the Kerr metric is actually valid for real-world cases of solid rotating bodies. If there is sufficient interest and when I have sufficient spare time, I might do some numerical calculations using real data to see what difference using the Kerr metric makes.
